# Azure SAS token AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, sas-token

I have created azure storage account. I have created file storage. I have generated SAS token. when I try to access file using sas token showing error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

I am able to generate  SAS token. when I try to access file in file storage throwing exception. I have tried to copy and paste url on browser throws error "

```
<Error>
       <Code>AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch</Code>
       <Message>
       This request is not authorized to perform this operation using 
        this resource type. RequestId:4cbc0cbe-401a-00c2-2edf- 
        202bc4000000 Time:2019-06-12T05:26:39.4816687Z
        </Message>
        </Error>"
```

### Code I am using to Generate SAS token

Static string GetAccountSASToken()

```
      SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new 
                          SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | 
                    SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | 
                    SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List,
                     Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.File,
        ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
        Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly,


    };
```

### Code I am using to access file

```
 XDocument objdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath+ sasToken);
```

After loading file to XDocument I have to perform some read and write operations.Please help in finding mistake that I am doing

Comment: From where are you loading the XML document- blob storage or file storage?

Comment: File Storage @GauravMantri

Comment: Are you still facing the problem or is it fixed?

Comment: Fixed sir. I have changed    ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service to ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object. Thank you sir.

Comment: Awesome! Please put your fix as an answer. It might help someone in future.

Comment: @user3404686, Please put your fix as an answer.

Answer (score 9):

I was encountering the same problem, and the solution from user3404686 (2019-07-13) is correct. After the fact it's much clearer, but when it's still a problem without resolution it can be baffling.

Resource types are authorised independently of each other, rather than there being a hierarchy, ie 'service' does not include 'container' and 'object' authorisations (which was my misunderstanding).

The [storageservices API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) describes how resource type permissions are assigned:

> - Service (s): Access to service-level APIs (e.g., Get/Set Service Properties, Get Service Stats, List Containers/Queues/Tables/Shares)
> - Container (c): Access to container-level APIs (e.g., Create/Delete Container, Create/Delete Queue, Create/Delete Table, Create/Delete
>   Share, List Blobs/Files and Directories)
> - Object (o): Access to object-level APIs for blobs, queue messages, table entities, and files(e.g. Put Blob, Query Entity, Get Messages,
>   Create File, etc.)

Further down in the same document, it provides examples of the service, resource type and permissions required for various operations that you may be using, allowing minimum-required-permissions granularity with regard to assigning permissions to a service using the SA token.

After understanding this, the error code AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch makes more sense - the resource type(s) the SAS token is authorised for, mismatches the resource types you're attempting to access.

Answer (score 5):

In SharedAccessAccountPolicy I have changed

```
ResourceTypes =SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service to
 ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object. Then It's working for me.
```